# How do I filter an array of dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary, filter

I have an array of libraries called `uniLib`. This is how it looks when I print it (this is just a small part):

> ["Université de Limoges": "France", "Vytautas Magnus University": "Lithuania", "Universidade Federal de Sergipe": "Brazil", "Instituto Politécnico de Lisboa": "Portugal", "Universidad de San Buenaventura": "Colombia", "Universitas Widyatama": "Indonesia", "Zhengzhou University of Technology": "China"]

We have a list of universities with the corresponding country and I would like to filter this dictionary by country, for example "france", and I should get a new array of dictionaries (or array of universities if possible). I am pretty new to Swift. I have been looking around for a while but I can't find anything to solve this problem.

This is how my array looks and how it's defined:

```
universityNames =  json[].arrayValue.map {$0["name"].stringValue}
countryNames =  json[].arrayValue.map {$0["country"].stringValue}

// merge arrays
var uniLib : [String:String] = [:]
for (index, element) in universityNames.enumerated() {
uniLib[element] = countryNames[index] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this :).

```
let universities = ["Université de Limoges": "France", "Vytautas Magnus University": "Lithuania", "Universidade Federal de Sergipe": "Brazil", "Instituto Politécnico de Lisboa": "Portugal", "Universidad de San Buenaventura": "Colombia", "Universitas Widyatama": "Indonesia", "Zhengzhou University of Technology": "China"]

func filterUniversities(country: String) -> [String] {
    return universities
        .compactMap { tuple in
            return tuple.value == country ? tuple.key : nil
        }
}

print(filterUniversities(country: "France"))
```

This will return `["Université de Limoges"]` which is I hope what you're looking for based on the question.

**Updated solution based on the comment:**

I'm not 100% sure what the expected result is so I created two variants:

```
let allUniversities = [
    ["Université de Limoges": "France", "Universidad de San Buenaventura": "Colombia", "Universitas Widyatama": "Indonesia", "Zhengzhou University of Technology": "China"],
    ["Universidade Federal de Sergipe": "Brazil", "Vytautas Magnus University": "Lithuania"],
    ["Instituto Politécnico de Lisboa": "Portugal", "Sorbonne": "France"]
]

func filterUniversities(country: String) -> [String] {
    return allUniversities
        .lazy
        .reduce([String]()) { (result, universities) in
            let filteredUniversities = universities.compactMap { $0.value == country ? $0.key : nil }

            return result + filteredUniversities
        }
}

print(filterUniversities(country: "France"))

func filterUniversityDictionaries(country: String) -> [[String: String]] {
    return allUniversities.lazy.filter { $0.values.contains(country) }
}

print(filterUniversityDictionaries(country: "France"))
```

This will give you following result:

```
["Université de Limoges", "Sorbonne"]

[["Zhengzhou University of Technology": "China", "Universidad de San Buenaventura": "Colombia", "Université de Limoges": "France", "Universitas Widyatama": "Indonesia"], ["Instituto Politécnico de Lisboa": "Portugal", "Sorbonne": "France"]]
```

Comment: The thing is this is just a small part of my array. I have multiple dictionaries that have France as a country. So I want to filter it and get an array back with all the dictionaries that have France as a country

Answer (score 0):

```
uniLib.lazy                         // Lazy so we don't have to allocate a temporary
    .filter { $0.value == country } // Find key/value pairs where value == country
    .map { $0.key }                 // Return the key (name)
```

The only reason to bother with `lazy` here is if `uniLib` were pretty large, and the `filter` step would tend to find a lot of elements. Without lazy, there is a temporary dictionary created by `filter` and immediately thrown away.